# Visualisation of a 3-person 3-good economy

Tags: pure-exchange-economy, edgeworth-box

Are there any theoretical or practical ways to visualise such an economy? I understand that a 2-person 3-good economy is visualised by a 3D Edgeworth Box (a cube), but what about a 3-person 3-good one?

Comment: @user18214 i'm going to need to describe a trading process of two-person coalitions in a 3-3 economy that leads to equllibrium. is it going to be difficult?

Comment: @user18214 as in, difficult without having a visualisation at hand.